# connecting to sql server express 2008 remotely

Tags: sql-server, remote-access

i have a beginners question, and i apologize if it is stupid.

i am a beginner at sql server. i can do sql pretty well, but i dont know much about connecting.

i have:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and SQL EXPRESS
```

what is the process of allowing remote connections to it?

i would like to leave my laptop online at home with the management studio running and would like to access my home sql server through a remote connection.

i would like to know

how do i allow one of my databases to accept remote connections?
what would the connection string be? just my laptop's IP address or what?
is it dangerous to accept remote connections?
i have done the following BTW:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151204091559/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx)

and when i do this it works:

```
SQLCMD -e -s localhost\sqlexpress,2301
```

however when i try to do this:

```
sqlcmd -e -s my.ip.add.ress\sqlexpress,2301
```

it does NOT work

anyway, after i do get this to work how would i connect to a specific db??

Answer (score 1):

As a first note, you aren't enabling remote access to the database, but rather the instance that the DB(s) are in. It isn't dangerous to enable remote connections as long as you have strong security in the credentials, whether they are windows or SQL auth. To use features like replication, and make an express instance a subscriber, you need to enable remote connections.

1. Open the SQL Server Surface Area Configuration, since this is Express, remote connections are disabled by default.
2. Once you are in The SA Config window, click on Surface Area Config for Services and    Connections.
3. Click on Remote Connections under Database Engine
4. Select Local and Remote Connections, and choose your type. (TCP, named pipes, or both)

If you have done all that, make sure you have also started the SQL browser service on the machine.